# Detect embeded object in webview

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, uiwebview

I was just wondering if using the private API it is possible to detect embeded videos and also get their src URL?

This would be a huge help thank u so much.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the public API if you're wiling to write a little bit of Javascript and have it run in the context of the page, returning you whatever you want.

For example:

```
NSString * js = @"var myLink=document.getElementById('well-known-id'); myLink.href;";
NSString * url = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:js];
```